# How To Associate Different Oauth2 Logins?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, gitlab, coveralls

I have a webapp with 2 login options: using your Github account or your GitLab account.

At the moment, these 2 logins are treated as different accounts: login with Github, see only your Github repos; login with GitLab, see only your GitLab stuff.

However, I notice apps such as Coveralls.io managed to link the logins: if you login with Github and GitLab, then you will see all your repos (Github *and* GitLab repos, no matter what future login options you choose).

So, how does Coveralls know that it's the same user?

Same in StackOverflow: if I originally authenticate with Github, I get an account and if later I authenticate with GMail, it's the same account. How is this achieved?

The only option I can think of is the e-mail address registered with the different Oauth providers: if it's the same, then wire different logins to the same account.

Answer (score 2):

This is doable because the app in question links a generic user account with identities related to each OAuth provider.

You can see an example of this in https://jumpstartrails.com/, the SaaS application created by Chris Oliver, creator of https://gorails.com/. That app implements this very pattern.

Also, this GoRails video by Chris may explain the approach:

Login with Multiple OAuth Providers using Omniauth:
https://gorails.com/episodes/login-with-multiple-oauth-providers?autoplay=1